# Get files from _layouts folder in SharePoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint, spweb

I'm currently working on a project where I'm adding docx-files to the Layout folder in Visual Studio and then use those ducment files to create Content Types.

The problem is that I can't get the document files programmatically. Using the web browser I can get the files but not using web.GetFolder();. The code is running in a Feature Receiver when a feature is activated.

```
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;

SPFolder docTempFolder = web.GetFolder("_LAYOUTS/Projekt/DocumentTemplates");
```

This code give me a collection with zero files.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Directory Path to 12 Hive programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943933/get-directory-path-to-12-hive-programmatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SPFolder` is for getting objects from SharePoint document libraries/lists. You can't access files in your **file system** (the 14 hive) by trying to cast them as an `SPFolder`. Also you can't use `SPWeb.GetFolder` as the files are nowhere near your web. They are on your harddisk.

You could get the 14 hive by using `GetGenericSetupPath`, so something like this would work:

```
var path = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Projekt\DocumentTemplates");
```

This path you could now Access with regular stream readers, `System.IO.File` etc.

---

**EDIT:** For SharePoint 2013 and above the mentioned method is obsolete as in newer SharePoint versions references to the `_layouts` folder always contain the SharePoint version in the path (e.g. `/_layouts/15` for SharePoint 2013 `/_layouts/14` for SharePoint 2010.

The new method is [`SPUtility.GetVersionedGenericSetupPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getversionedgenericsetuppath.aspx). The method does *not exist* in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: I know this is old but people will find it on Google. This is now obsolete in SP2013. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.getgenericsetuppath.aspx